# Help with designing a circuit with logic gates

Tags: digital-logic

I want to build a circuit with the following design:

- 3 inputs
- 1 NOT gate
- 2 AND gates
- 1 OR gate

This is my truth table:

```
 I1 | I2 | I3 || output

 0  | 0  |  0 ||   0       
 0  | 0  |  1 ||   0       
 0  | 1  |  0 ||   1       
 0  | 1  |  1 ||   1       
 1  | 0  |  0 ||   0       
 1  | 0  |  1 ||   1       
 1  | 1  |  0 ||   0       
 1  | 1  |  1 ||   1
```

Can someone help me with what components should I buy?

I know there are chips that have AND/OR/NOT gates, but I was wondering if there's a single one that have all of the ones I need - if not, then what should I use specifically?

Comment: Any reason it has to be those particular gates? For example a package with with four NOR gates could be used to make the logical equivalent of the NOT gate and the OR gate.

Comment: Despite the mention of buying components, this sounds somewhat like a homework question. While homework questions are not expressly forbidden, you are more likely to get favorable response and perhaps answers, if you explain in your question *what you have figured out so far and what you are stuck at*.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I couldn't resist trying a Karnaugh map in MathJax ...

Comment: Wow. Thanks guys I got my answer. Don't worry it's not homework :). I mentioned these gates because I used Karnaugh map, but it is not mandatory - sorry for misleading. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Same deal as Keelan's answer, but using a single 74xx00 series NAND chip (4 gates):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fywteb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

First step is filling a Karnaugh map. The first one for little bit help filling the map:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{I1}\cdot\text{I2}\cdot\text{I3} & \text{I1}\cdot\text{I2} & \overline{\text{I1}}\cdot\text{I2} & \overline{\text{I1}}\cdot\overline{\text{I2}} & \text{I1}\cdot\overline{\text{I2}} \\
\hline
\text{I3}            & 111 & 011 & 001 & 101 \\
\hline
\overline{\text{I3}} & 110 & 010 & 000 & 100 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Then fill the truth table 
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
& \text{I1}\cdot\text{I2} & \overline{\text{I1}}\cdot\text{I2} & \overline{\text{I1}}\cdot\overline{\text{I2}} & \text{I1}\cdot\overline{\text{I2}} \\
\hline
\text{I3}            & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\overline{\text{I3}} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

And solve:
\$
\text{output} = \boxed{\text{I1}\cdot\text{I3}+\overline{\text{I1}}\cdot\text{I2}}
\$

From here follow one of the implementations in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your output follows this formula:

```
output = (I1 & I3) | (!I1 & I2)
```

A circuit would look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fubOJQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For logic gates, you can use the [7400 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits):

- AND: 7408, e.g.
- OR: 7432, e.g.
- NOT: 74LS04, e.g.

Comment: Not bad : for bonus points, you can redraw it using four 2-input NAND gates, i.e. a 7400.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I sticked to the parts mentioned by the OP and didn't think of it any further :) I see Bitrex now added your suggestion as an answer so thanks, but I won't add it.